# ionic + swiper from v1.2

Tags: ionic-framework, swiper.js

I'm trying to implement the new swiper from the 1.2 ionics version and Im having a hard time.
I'm trying to create a nested swiper with a dynamic name ( inside the sliders attribute I guess - HTML line 20 to create it and JS line 59 to watch it).

The main issue is that Id like to add/remove some slides from the nested swiper.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pgVMqw?editors=1010

Do you have any idea ?

Thanks a lot !

HTML :

```
<ion-slides id="sliderPerson-{{$index}}" options="options2" slider="data.sliderPerson">
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use  $scope.data.sliderPerson.removeSlide($index) and $scope.data.sliderPerson.append(slides). 
You might have to use $scope.data.sliderPerson.update() to manually update the slider afterwords.

Reference:http://www.idangero.us/swiper/api/